# Where `clasp` puts `.gs` files? Troubleshooting compiler errors on `clasp push`

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

Where locally can I find the `.gs` files that `clasp push` generates?

I'm using `clasp push` to compile a TypeScript file into a `.gs` file and upload it to Apps Script, but I'm getting an error:

```
$ clasp push                                                                                                                    
| Pushing files...Push failed. Errors:                                                                                                                 
{ Error: Syntax error: ParseError: Unexpected token . line: 253 file: Code.gs
```

The line number in the error is in terms of the compiled `.gs` file, which does not get uploaded because of the error. I need to find the compiled local copy of the .gs file so I can inspect it and fix the error in the original `.ts` typescript file, but where is the `.gs` file?

My TypeScript file compiles without errors using `tsc`.

Comment: submitted a github issue: https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/806

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on `@google/clasp` for compiling your typescript into `.gs`

Trust me (as a major contributor to clasp) you'll be best by handling the compilation yourself, with clasp only being used to push your compiled files.

I have a github template which may get you started: https://github.com/PopGoesTheWza/ts-gas-project-starter

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Compile the typescript file, say `Code.ts`, into javascript yourself using `tsc`.

Then validate the resulting local `Code.js`, for example by

- Pasting its contents into the `Code.gs` file in the Apps Script code editor. When you hit save, you'll hopefully see the same error.
- Or, with `node --check Code.js`

This will show you an error in terms of a file that you have access to.